# Issue with new RStudio Install

Tags: installation, rstudio

With an install of RStudio, certain packages bring up issues that states "the x command requires the command line developer tools. Would you like to install them now" and when "install" is clicked, then it states there is no software to download. Any insights?

Comment: Adding that this is from a MacBook Pro and that the "x" command is often different depending on the package that gets installed.

Comment: I'm not understanding the issue. What packages? Please provide an actual output of the error. What do you mean by "with an install of Rstudio"?